# CS50 tideman struggling

Tags: c, cs50

I'm new to this site and I have been trying to do Tideman of the problem set 3 of CS50 course and have been struggling to this problem for days, please help me find the logical error in my code but please don't post the solution. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    int compare[MAX * (MAX - 1)];
    int locked_count = 0;
    for (int n=0; n < pair_count; n++)
    {
        circle_check(pairs[n], compare, 0, locked_count);
        if(circle_check_out != 0)
        {
            locked[pairs[n].winner][pairs[n].loser]=true;
            locked_count++;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Check wether circle
void circle_check( pair check, int compare[], int comp_numb, int locked_count)
{
    if (compare[comp_numb+1] == compare[0] && comp_numb == locked_count)
    {
        circle_check_out = 0;
        return;
    }
    else if (compare[comp_numb+1] != compare[0] && comp_numb == locked_count && comp_numb != 0)
    {
        circle_check_out = 1;
        return;
    }
    for (int n=0; n < locked_count; n++)
    {
        if (locked[pairs[n].winner][check.winner] == true)
        {
            circle_check(pairs[n], compare, comp_numb+1, locked_count);
            compare[comp_numb] = check.loser;
            compare[comp_numb+1] = check.winner;
        }
    }
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    bool dominate=true;
    for (int win=0; win < candidate_count; win++)
    {
        for (int lose=0; lose < candidate_count; lose++)
        {
            if(locked[lose][win]==true)
                dominate=false;
        }
    if (dominate==true)
        printf("%s",candidates[win]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is "Tideman of the problem set 3", exactly?

Comment: For starter, your `compare` local variable in `lock_pairs` is uninitialized, that is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Take this as a good time to learn how to *debug* your code. For example how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: I did try debugger and I still can not figure it out

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: "find the logical error" What makes you think that there is a logical error? What are the symptoms? For which input/data? Please provide a [mre] demonstrating the symptom.

Comment: Please explain your approach. What is the basic idea you are using? I.e. please explain how you think that your code should arrive at the correct result.

Comment: Thank you all for replying, here is my thought process. I will assume that you did this problem or at least understand what I'm trying to achieve because if I explain everything, it will get very long and complicated.
Firstly, I create circle_check function which takes a pair to check if locking that pair will create a circle. For example, if I already locked in 2 pairs Bob>Alice and Alice>Charlie(winner>loser) and I want to lock another pair Charlie>Bob. I will store Bob as compare[0] and Charlie S compare[1].

Comment: Then go through all other locked pairs to find a pair that may contain Charlie as loser which is Alice>Charlie (which represent in code as pair[n]) and store Charlie as compare[1] and Alice as compare[2] do the same as Bob>Alice. Now it will check if compare[3](which is Bob) == compare[0] and, if yes it will define circle_check_out as 1 indicating that there is a circle and if the last pair is not Charlie>Bob but Charlie>Micheal and I run out of locked pair to find (comp_numb == locked_count) circle_check_out as 0

Comment: Next, in lock_pairs, if the pair is is Charlie>Micheal I will lock it and continue the loop if it is Charlie>Bob(which creates a circle) I will not lock it and continue the loop.
Hope you can understand what I'm trying to say and give me some feedback.

Comment: For print_winner, I think I figured out what I did wrong